# Поиск Яндекс по собственной базе данных

Tags: база-данных, яндекс-поиск

Народ, такой вопрос. Если я поставлю на свой сайт Яндекс поиск и изменю базу данных на свою, он будет искать информацию только по моей базе данных?

Comment: Или же если можете киньте ссылочку на Ролик в Ютубе где показывают как написать свой движок для поиска. А то я нашел только 2 ролика а они непонятны для меня.